# face landmark detection cnn loss not converging in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, cnn, computer-vision

I am trying to build face landmark detection model using simple regression.I used celeba dataset which has 5 points hence 10 output units.I used grayscale and normalized image as input.
Here is my model

```
    self.model = models.Sequential()
    self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (4, 4), activation='relu', input_shape=(218, 178,1)))#l1
    self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (4, 4), activation='relu'))#l2
    self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (4, 4), activation='relu'))#l3
    self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (4, 4), activation='relu'))#l4
    self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    self.model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D((3, 3)))
    self.model.add(layers.Flatten())
    self.model.add(layers.Dense(16))
    self.model.add(layers.Dense(10))
```

Here is my loss function

```
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),loss='mse')
```

Here loss is stuck around 18 and doesn't go below that. I tried various configuration of CNN architecture like adding and removing layers and I also tried with changing learning rate  but no use.

Please anyone point me in right direction. How can I debug this network.
(For this I only used first 100 images of dataset)

Comment: Make the network bigger i.e. try 64 throughout. Also, the last Dense of 16 is too less. First, overfit the train set. Preprocess the image too.

Answer (score 0):

Use a standard pretrained network like ResNet, Effnet or even VGG16 for feature extraction and put a regression layer in the end.

Now, talking about your network. FIrst of all, the image size is not square, make it! Don't use even valued kernels (3 and 5 are mostly used). Number of filters increase with depth, yours don't follow a pattern.

Lastly, 100 images are nothing for these behemoths, give it more data.

Better stick to a pretrained model.

Comment: I am doing this for practice not for any actual implementation. So I want to do it from scratch

Comment: And also making it square made worse

Comment: Make smallest side 256 and take 224x224 center crop. That's how you need to do it. Also, did you correct your network first. Correct that then make observations about the images.